# Mailcore2 on iOS8

Tags: ios8, xcode6, mailcore2

My existing project failed to build after upgrading from Xcode 5.1.1 to Xcode 6.0. I have already tried removing the 'Externals' folder and doing a full clean. 
While trying to find a solution I even updated the following files to add SDK version 8.0:

- build-mailcore2-ios copy.sh
- build-mailcore2-ios.sh
- prepare-ctemplate-ios.sh
- prepare-icu4c-ios.sh
- prepare-libetpan-ios.sh
- prepare-tidy-ios.sh

**by adding the following:**

```
if xcodebuild -showsdks|grep iphoneos8.0 >/dev/null ; then
    sdkversion=8.0
    devicearchs="armv7 armv7s arm64"
```

**But it still fails to run the shell script. Following is the transcript of the error:**

```
/bin/sh /Volumes/Disk\ 1/Apps/NoMyID/MailCore/Externals/builds/workdir/20140926183134/src/libetpan/build-mac/update.sh
/Volumes/Disk 1/Apps/NoMyID/MailCore/Externals/builds/workdir/20140926183134/src/libetpan/build-mac/update.sh: line 25: test: too many arguments
configuring
configure failed
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    ExternalBuildToolExecution libetpan-prepare-ios
(1 failure)
failed
Current branch master is up to date.
building ctemplate
build for i386
/Volumes/Disk 1/Apps/NoMyID/MailCore/scripts/../Externals/builds/workdir/20140926183156/log/ctemplate-build.log
configure: WARNING: if you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used
configure: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in `pwd`
configure: WARNING: Impossible to determine how to use pthreads with shared libraries and -nostdlib
src/template.cc:158:20: warning: unused variable 'kDefaultTemplateDirectory' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const char * const kDefaultTemplateDirectory = kCWD;   // "./"
                   ^
1 warning generated.
src/template_dictionary.cc:76:26: warning: unused variable 'kAnnotateOutput' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const char* const kAnnotateOutput = "__ctemplate_annotate_output__";
                         ^
In file included from src/template_dictionary.cc:50:
./src/indented_writer.h:123:7: warning: private field 'original_indentation_' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
  int original_indentation_;
      ^
2 warnings generated.
src/template.cc:158:20: warning: unused variable 'kDefaultTemplateDirectory' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const char * const kDefaultTemplateDirectory = kCWD;   // "./"
                   ^
1 warning generated.
src/template_dictionary.cc:76:26: warning: unused variable 'kAnnotateOutput' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const char* const kAnnotateOutput = "__ctemplate_annotate_output__";
                         ^
In file included from src/template_dictionary.cc:50:
./src/indented_writer.h:123:7: warning: private field 'original_indentation_' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
  int original_indentation_;
      ^
2 warnings generated.
src/template.cc:158:20: warning: unused variable 'kDefaultTemplateDirectory' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const char * const kDefaultTemplateDirectory = kCWD;   // "./"
                   ^
1 warning generated.
src/template_dictionary.cc:76:26: warning: unused variable 'kAnnotateOutput' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const char* const kAnnotateOutput = "__ctemplate_annotate_output__";
                         ^
1 warning generated.
libtool: link: warning: `-version-info/-version-number' is ignored for convenience libraries
src/template.cc:158:20: warning: unused variable 'kDefaultTemplateDirectory' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const char * const kDefaultTemplateDirectory = kCWD;   // "./"
                   ^
1 warning generated.
src/template_dictionary.cc:76:26: warning: unused variable 'kAnnotateOutput' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const char* const kAnnotateOutput = "__ctemplate_annotate_output__";
                         ^
1 warning generated.
libtool: link: warning: `-version-info/-version-number' is ignored for convenience libraries
libtool: link: warning: `-version-info/-version-number' is ignored for convenience libraries
libtool: link: warning: `-version-info/-version-number' is ignored for convenience libraries
src/template_dictionary.cc:76:26: warning: unused variable 'kAnnotateOutput' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const char* const kAnnotateOutput = "__ctemplate_annotate_output__";
                         ^
1 warning generated.
src/template_dictionary.cc:76:26: warning: unused variable 'kAnnotateOutput' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const char* const kAnnotateOutput = "__ctemplate_annotate_output__";
                         ^
1 warning generated.
src/tests/template_unittest.cc:140:6: warning: unused function 'StreqExcept' [-Wunused-function]
bool StreqExcept(const char* a, const char* b, const char* except) {
     ^
1 warning generated.
src/tests/template_unittest.cc:140:6: warning: unused function 'StreqExcept' [-Wunused-function]
bool StreqExcept(const char* a, const char* b, const char* except) {
     ^
src/tests/template_unittest.cc:167:6: warning: unused function 'IntEqVerbose' [-Wunused-function]
bool IntEqVerbose(int a, int b) {
     ^
2 warnings generated.
src/tests/htmlparser_cpp_test.cc:94:18: warning: unused variable 'kMaxFileSize' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int kMaxFileSize = 1000000;
                 ^
1 warning generated.
src/tests/htmlparser_cpp_test.cc:94:18: warning: unused variable 'kMaxFileSize' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int kMaxFileSize = 1000000;
                 ^
1 warning generated.
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
make: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 64
build of ctemplate failed
Showing first 200 notices only
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around with the shell scripts for a while, I downloaded the latest commit from Github (https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2). Alas, it worked. I should have gone for this option before.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the downloaded code from the "External" folder doesn't work. Therefore i stored a working "External" folder and whenever this happens, i overwrite the non-working "External" folder with the working one.

Before i compile the code, i disconnect my MacBook from every internet connection.

After it passes the MailCore2 Library compile task, i connect to the internet connection again.

But i'll give it a try to clone everything first whenever this error occures.

**EDIT**

Now i used the GitHub Application, cloning the MailCore2 project and linking the framework in the XCode Project. And this workes!